# How to connect SQL Server in Flex Desktop Application or Flash as3 Application?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

SQLConnector.swc => Only it supports for mySQL
but there is no SQL Server side library for as3 applications.

if any one flex/flash desktop developers plzz help me!!

Regards,
RajeshKumar S

Comment: Are you sure? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLConnection.html

Comment: ya. sure. Are you tried any other alternative way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQLConnection supports SQLLite, which is a local / file based database; not mySQL or SQL Server which are client/server databases.

To my knowledge, there is no built in way to connect to a client server database.  In theory you could write your own database drivers using [socket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html) connections.  I would not expect that to be trivial.

I recommend you use an application server (Java, ColdFusion, PHP, .NET, etc.. ) that can easily access the database and your Flex based UI.